# cannot display radio button inside accordion in html 5

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I cannot display radio button when i am using with accordion.label only displayed.

HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
<section id="accordion">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="check-1" name="acr" />
      <label for="check-1">Hardware</label>
      <article>
    <div class="person1" style="float:left; display:inline-block;margin-left:0px;border: 1px solid black;border-color:#C4C4C4;width:767px">
            <span style="float:left;width: 90;height:130;display:inline-block;margin-left:50px;position:relative;">
                <img src="image/cmp1.jpg"  width="100" height="130" style:"float:left;margin:0 5px 0 0;height:800"/>
            </span>

            <span style="float:left;">
                <div style="background-color:#F0F0F0;width:500px;">
                     <h1 style="padding-top: 0.3cm;font-size:12pt;padding-bottom:0.3cm;">Processor</h1>
                     <p style="display:block;padding-left:0.3cm;padding-bottom:0.3cm;padding-right:0.3cm;font-size:11pt;font-family:Courier New Italic;text-align: justify;font-weight: normal;">Choose the processor that best meets your performance needs. Your MacBook Pro comes as standard with the 2.5GHz dual-core Intel Core i5 processor. For even faster performance, configure your MacBook Pro with the 2.9GHz dual-core Intel Core i7 processor.</p>
                </div>

                <div style="background-color:gray;width:500px;">
                    <input name="r1" id="macbook_processor_065_0731_1" type="radio" value="y" checked="">2.5GHz Dual-core Intel Core i5, Turbo Boost up to 3.1GHz<br>
                    <input name="r1" id="macbook_processor_065_0732_2" type="radio" value="n">2.9GHz Dual-core Intel Core i7, Turbo Boost up to 3.6GHz
                </div>
            </span>
     .
     .
```

if i don't use with accordion, it works well.can anyone help me?

Comment: I can see the radio button, what exactly do you want ?

Comment: i cannot see radio button.is there any mistakes in my code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vadjn2an/10/

Check this, it has the label Hardware with your radio button

Comment: i don't need radio with Hardware label.just near to 2.5GHz..

Comment: You dont need it with Hardware, so remove the line before label Hardware and you can also see the radio button near 2.5 ghz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the radio button before hardware

```
<div id="container">
    <section id="accordion">
        <div>

          <label for="check-1">Hardware</label>
          <article>
        <div class="person1" style="float:left; display:inline-block;margin-left:0px;border: 1px solid black;border-color:#C4C4C4;width:767px">
                <span style="float:left;width: 90;height:130;display:inline-block;margin-left:50px;position:relative;">
                    <img src="image/cmp1.jpg"  width="100" height="130" 
                     style:"float:left;margin:0 5px 0 0;height:800"/>
                </span>

                <span style="float:left;">
                    <div style="background-color:#F0F0F0;width:500px;">

                    <h1 style="padding-top: 0.3cm;font-size:12pt;padding-bottom:0.3cm;">Processor</h1>
                    <p style="display:block;padding-left:0.3cm;padding-bottom:0.3cm;padding-right:0.3cm;font-size:11pt;font-family:Courier New Italic;text-align: justify;font-weight: normal;">Choose the processor that best meets your performance needs. Your MacBook Pro comes as standard with the 2.5GHz dual-core Intel Core i5 processor. For even faster performance, configure your MacBook Pro with the 2.9GHz dual-core Intel Core i7 processor.
                    </p>
                    </div>

                    <div style="background-color:gray;width:500px;">
                        <input name="r1" id="macbook_processor_065_0731_1" type="radio" value="y" checked="">
                      2.5GHz Dual-core Intel Core i5, Turbo Boost up to 3.1GHz<br>
                    <input name="r1" id="macbook_processor_065_0732_2" type="radio" value="n">2.9GHz Dual-core Intel Core i7, Turbo Boost up to 3.6GHz
                    </div>
        </span>
```